# error of Cannot determine size of graphic

Tags: graphics, errors

I compile my LaTeX code as LaTeX ,it give an error `Error: LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in scope.jpg (no BoundingBox).` If I compile as PdfLateX not errors...i need my output as a PDF...what is a solution for that?

I add figures using,

```
\begin{figure}[ht]

\begin{center}

\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.5cm]{scope.jpg}

\end{center}

\begin{center}

\caption[sss]{sss}

\end{center}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Use `pdflatex`; `latex` can't load JPEG files.